# Get, edit and update rows of data in other tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a Borrowers Tracker in google sheets. I have a database which look like thisL

[image: database]

I want to get a specific row by searching Borrowers Slip Reference Number and edit it if the tools are returned, put the return slip ref number and make a button to update it on the database. The tab for return reporting must be like this.

[image: tab return]

I am aware that you can use filter data for this but I want to make a separate form for updating return report because I will lock the database sheet and only allow my teammate to enter data using the return reporting tab. Any help will be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your 1st and 2nd images. And also, I cannot understand your current issue, and I cannot understand `I am aware that you can use filter data for this but I want to make a separate form for updating return report because I will lock the database sheet and only allow my teammate to enter data using the return reporting tab.`. Can I ask you about the detail of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `I want to make a separate form for updating return report ` Have you written this script yet &/or thought through the specific steps to complete the process?  You have over-simplified a complex scenario, but if you can write this script then the search term will be simple.